# angular 2 checkbox binding error

Tags: angular, checkbox, input, conditional-statements

i am binding the checked attribute of checkbox with a model like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users;let userIndex=index;">
    <!--Some other code-->
    <td (click)="changeUserStatus(userIndex)">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{'userstatus'+userIndex}}" name="{{'userstatus'+userIndex}}" [checked]="(user.status==='true')?true:false"> 
       </label>
     </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**.ts**

```
changeUserStatus(index: string) {
    if (this.users[index].status === "false")
     this.users[index].status = "true";
     else this.users[index].status = "false";
}
```

I even checked this condition **(user.status==='true')?true:false** which is yielding true. But the checkbox isnt getting checked no matter what.

Please help!!

Comment: What is hapening inside  changeUserStatus?

Comment: I have updated the question with my latest code . But still it isnt working

Comment: Why are you putting true inside quote ? Try this  `<input type="checkbox" id="{{'userstatus'+userIndex}}" name="{{'userstatus'+userIndex}}" [checked]="(user.status)?true:false">`

Comment: Because sometimes the boolean also gets converted to string and passed to function , so just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.

change the html as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{'userstatus'+userIndex}}" name="{{'userstatus'+userIndex}}" [checked]="(user.status==='true')?true:''">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model instead of id. Try read these documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

There's some reason the angular not render your input attribute

Comment: this is referring angular 2. and you dont require ng-model binding to acheive this.